# Impossibility to use variable concatenation on java

Tags: java, variables, concatenation

i am a beginner with java and i am bloked with a variable concatenation problem.

I create a naval battle game and i want update all cases of sea on the front-end from an array.

On php, we can  use loop for that, but not on java:

```
for( int i = 0; i< tverite1.length; ++i){
    for( int j = 0; j<tverite1[i].length; ++j){
        button_+i+j.setText("0"); 
    }
}
tverite is an array with each case of the sea
button_x_y buttons are the sea of the front-end
```

I need help because i dont see some issue on the web and i dont want write 100 lines only for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in java.
You should consider using an array of 2 dimensions, something like:

```
for( int i = 0; i< tverite1.length; ++i){
    for( int j = 0; j<tverite1[i].length; ++j){
        buttons[i][j].setText("0"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is better to go all over the button's container (looping) and setting text "0". That way you avoid to add the arrays variables.

Comment: @JGutierrezC: I strongly beg to differ. You're much better grouping like components into arrays or ArrayLists and iterating through these collections then using the kludge of trying to go (recursively mind you) through all of a container's components, looking for buttons and setting them. The latter technique invites hard to remove bugs. 1+ to Arley for this answer.

Comment: @JGutierrezC - that assumes that you want to set all of the buttons in the container.  The OP appears to be trying to set specific buttons (in an array).  There is nothing to say that there aren't other buttons ... that shouldn't be set.

Comment: jajajajajaja! Is not that hard to put all buttons in a container as it is a **naval battle game** and all the buttons are together.If not, he could add peculiarities to the buttons or components that he doesn't want to include in the actions.

Comment: @JGutierrezC: as someone who has created many Java GUI's I can say this: no it's not hard to do what you're suggesting, but again it's a very bad design. Again, it introduces the possibility of creating hard to debug errors as it allows for changing the state of components in a very indirect way. You should not be recommending this.

Comment: Hard to debug errors? Why is that? He is not adding listeners to the buttons or something critical. He is only asking for setting text "0" to all buttons or maybe latter setEnable state to true or false. if he wants to add something specific to each two or three or four... buttons, then he could put the buttons into an array. When i'm making a mistake in any answer, i simply accept my mistake and delete it. This time my answer is better than save each (of 100) button into the array. As adding it implies: **tverite1.add(button1)** and button2.. and button3...

Comment: And i have created many simple GUIs and Enterprise GUI applications too :)

Comment: @JGutierrezC - The votes would suggest that other people don't share your opinion.  And picking a silly way to initialize the buttons / array doesn't help your argument.

Comment: @Stephen C - Jajajajajaja! Silly way... if you think is better to write 100 lines of code to add each button into the arrays, you're not that smart. :)

Comment: Quoting the PO... **"i dont want write 100 lines only for that"** ;)

Comment: @JGutierrezC - I'm not talking about his code.  I'm talking about >>your<< silly idea that you have to initialize the buttons like that.  Obviously you don't, and your suggestion that you do is simply helping to demonstrate how weak your argument is.  Hint: use a loop/loops to create the buttons AND populate the array.  It is not rocket science.

Comment: thanks for your help,
i have well understood i must create map that does associate names of buttons into buttons[i][j] for use this form:buttons[i][j].setText("0");

Answer (score 2):

The problem is basic: Java is not PHP and doesn't allow variable concatenation, so don't even consider it.

And the answer is just as basic: just use an array or a Collection such as an ArrayList. Then you can easily iterate through your array or collection when the need arises. If your problem is that you want to associate an object with a String, then consider using a different type of collection, a Map such as a HashMap.

Comment: Indeed, Java is not PHP. More generally, it is very useful when learning another language to read a complete book or tutorial about it. Attempts to port idioms from other languages, rather than studying the idioms of the language in which you are writing, often lead to frustration and poor quality code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: amen and well said!

Answer (score 1):

This sure answer your questions:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/25316-Can-you-concatenate-variable-names-in-Java

You can't do that but you could try iterating between components as the answer below. I think is great

Comment: Hello there @Juan Sandoval, next time avoid answering link only answers. Provide some explanation or code and use the url as a source and not as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the concatenation in Java as you are following in PHP.

Instead of `button_+i+j.setText("0");` you need to take the button as a two dimensional array.

Something like: `button[i][j].setText("0");`

Comment: thanks for your help,
i have well understood i must create map that does associate each names of buttons into buttons[i][j] for use this form:
buttons[i][j].setText("0");
?

Comment: @beaver: your comment above is confusing as you are stating "map" and showing an array. Please clarify your remaining problem by editing your *original question* above and describing the details of your current problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that on java, but you can get all items inside the button's container and setting text "0" that way.

For example:

```
public void initializeButtons(Container container) {
    Component[] components = container.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        //If you're using JButton, if not, change the type. This only asks if the component's
        //type is a button. You could add another clause if the buttons have something else special
        if(!(component instanceof JButton)){ //If the component is not a button we skip it.
            continue;
        }
        ((JButton)component).setText("0");
    }
}
```

That way you could add other actions to all buttons in the same way.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubt :)